# Why is subprocess returncode inconsistent with the Unix exit code?

Tags: python, subprocess

One example: an exit code of `136` (source: typing `$?` into a shell) appears as `-8` in the returncode variable. I assume this has something to do with the representation of negative numbers, but I can't find a pattern of 16 bits that could be interpreted both ways.

Comment: From the documentation: `A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).`

Comment: It's 8-bit (1-byte), which if signed is ranged from [-128, 127], and if unsigned from [0, 255].

Comment: 128 - 136 == -8.